# Problem with calling realloc inside function where an array is a parameter

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, realloc

I have a problem with realloc. Valgrind returns `8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1`. Whereas if I called the function `allocate` from main, it works. I don't understand what is the difference? It works if I put `free(tab)` inside the function`sth` but I need to do something with `tab` inside main. Can anyone help find a solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x{
    int a;
    char b;
};


void allocate( struct x **tab,int *size)
{
    *size = 1+2*(*size);
    *tab= realloc(*tab, (size_t) (*size) * sizeof (**tab));
}


void sth (struct x *tab, int *size)
{
    //do something here
    allocate(&tab, size);
}

int main(void)
{
    int size=0;
    struct x *tab=NULL;
    sth(tab, &size);
    //do sth here with tab
    free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `struct x **` to the `sth` function. Otherwise, you are modifying a copy of the pointer created in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `tab` of the function `sth` is a *copy of* what is passed and change to that won't affect what is passed. Therefore, `free(tab);` in the `main()` function means `free(NULL);`. This is defined to do nothing and it won't contribute for avoiding memory leak. Pass pointers to what should be modified to have functions modify what are passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x{
    int a;
    char b;
};


void allocate( struct x **tab,int *size)
{
    *size = 1+2*(*size);
    *tab= realloc(*tab, (size_t) (*size) * sizeof (**tab));
}


void sth (struct x **tab, int *size) // receive a pointer of struct x*
{
    //do something here
    // allocate(&(*tab), size);
    allocate(tab, size);
}

int main(void)
{
    int size=0;
    struct x *tab=NULL;
    sth(&tab, &size); // pass a pointer to what should be modified
    //do sth here with tab
    free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```